# Unable to log in to HyperProtect Virtual Server even with correct SSH key

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I've created a HyperProtect virtual server on IBM Cloud, but I'm unable to log in.

I followed the steps in the [getting started guide](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/hp-virtual-servers/getting-started.html), and I'm sure I've put in my ssh public key correctly (as in the [provisioning](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/hp-virtual-servers?topic=hp-virtual-servers-provision) section), but I get the following error when trying to log in over ssh:

```
root@<IP_ADDRESS>: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have tried to log in using both

```
ssh-agent
ssh root@<IP_ADDRESS>
```

and

```
ssh root@<IP_ADDRESS> -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

(In all of the above, I used the real IP of the machine, rather than the literal string `<IP_ADDRESS>`)

I have used this key to log in to another cloud service's VPS just fine, so I don't think the problem is on my end.

Is it possible the user should not be "root" as written in the docs?

**Edit**: Forgot to mention: I also followed the docs and made sure to wait at least 30 minutes after the machine was provisioned before trying to log in - no success.

Comment: "root" is the typical user and it is used consistently within the docs. Are you sure that you used the correct key? If yes, contact support or reprovision the server

Comment: I tried reprovisioning multiple times, and I'm certain I used the correct key. I did notice after one reprovisioning that port 22 didn't even accept connections - I even tried from multiple locations - so maybe the service is a bit buggy?

Answer (score 0):

the service may take about 30 minute for the network to be configured
[link to ibm docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/hp-virtual-servers?topic=hp-virtual-servers-troubleshooting)

Comment: I always waited more than 30 minutes, and on one occasion waited over an hour. I've edited my question to reflect this - thanks though!